# How to use database slug field to display a respective blog entry and URL

Tags: web2py

I am running a web2py web app that includes a blog. I use a slug field in the post database and would like to display the slug as part of the url (instead of the blog post id). I manage to pass the slug field as request.args to the post function, but can't display the related post - instead I am getting a 404 Page Not Found error. When I use the post.id field as request.args, the post is displayed correctly, but then the url shows the post id and not the slug field. I would like to use the slug mainly for SEO reasons. Any pointers would be great!

In my model I have:

```py
db.define_table('post',
                Field('title', unique=True),
                Field('subtitle'),
                Field('intro', 'text'),
                Field('body', 'text'),
                Field('body_mid', 'text'),
                Field('body_end', 'text'),
                Field('published_on', 'date'),
                Field('category'),
                Field('file1', 'upload'),
                Field('caption_one'),
                Field('file2', 'upload'),
                Field('caption_two'),
                Field('slug', 'string', compute=lambda r: r['title']),
                format = '%(title)s')
```

In my controller I have:

```py
#this selects all posts
def blog():
    post = db().select(db.post.ALL, orderby=~db.post.published_on)
    return dict(post=post)
#this selects a post based on request.args
def show():
    post = db.post(request.args(0, cast = int)) or redirect(URL('index'))
    return dict(post=post)
```

In the view for blog I have (this works):

{{for entry in post:}}
{{=LI(A(entry.title, _href=URL("show", args=entry.id)))}}                {{pass}}

When I change to (this does not work):
{{for entry in post:}}
{{=LI(A(entry.title, _href=URL("show", args=entry.slug)))}}                {{pass}}

How do I use the slug field correctly in order to show the slug in the URL and display the related database entry?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `db.post(id)` syntax requires the value passed to `db.post()` to be the record ID. If you want to select the record based on another field, you must do one of the following:

```
`db.post(slug=request.args(0))`
```

or:

```
`db(db.post.slug == request.args(0)).select().first()`
```

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Fetching-a-Row.

Comment: Thanks Anthony! This works well now and as intended!